# Restrict one user to see other users courses

Tags: moodle

I am kind of new to Moodle, but I am looking for the following:

I created two user(User1 and user2) from admin and both users have their own courses.

Structure is like:-

Admin have two Users:- User1 and User2

user1 have three course C1,C2,C3

user2 have two course C4,C5

And user1 and user2 should not see each others courses. Also, when the user clicks "All courses" he/she should still only see the assigned courses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a plugin for this.it helped me to resolve all my issue. Hope it will help others too.

for demo you can visit 
    http://demo.iomad.org/

Iomad is completely free. Like Moodle, anyone is free to download and use the software 
    https://github.com/iomad

Answer (score 0):

You may have to define a role for each user in `Settings > Site administration > Users > Permissions > Define roles Assign system`

There are more than a lot settings if you scroll down on create new role page.

And then assign that role to the each user from `Settings > Site administration > Users > Permissions > Assign system roles`

Though I am not entirely sure that this method will work as expected.

But this could be one of the options.